# JList text alignment

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jlist

I have a `JList` with items that I want to show two values. Is there a way to have it show a string name and then have a right justified string to show a value. Looking something like this:

```
Title__________________120
Title2_________________135
```

Is it possible to pass in two string to an item and have the first string display on the left and the second one on the right?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sure, implement a custom [renderer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JList.html#setCellRenderer%28javax.swing.ListCellRenderer%29).  You might return a `JPanel` with `BorderLayout` as the rendering component, with the LHS text in the `WEST`, and the RHS text in the `EAST`.

Another way is to shove HTML into the default renderer (a `JLabel`), using an HTML table that stretches across 100% of the width.  Though the custom renderer would be a better choice for a number of reasons (e.g. not presuming the type of the default renderer is a label).

---

BTW - perhaps you should consider using a `JTable` for this kind of functionality.  No hacks or custom classes needed.

---

> ..does the jtable allow selecting items?

Of course!  Here is an example taken directly from [How to Use Tables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) in the tutorial.  'Jane' is selected.

[image: Table with row selected]

A table is a little more effort to set up and get right, but it is well worth the effort.

> Would a JTable perform just as a JList ..

No, the table ultimately provides more functionality.  But the things it does which a list can also do, work (for the user) in much the same way.

Comment: Would a JTable perform just as a JList (sorry this is my first time using jlists and jtables so I'm unfamiliar). What I mean is the JList provides a nice interface for selecting values, but does the jtable allow selecting items?

Comment: See the edit, but especially look at the 'How to Use Tables' link.  That will explain most of what you need to know.

Comment: Awesome! Everyone here at stackoverflow always give nice detailed answers for even the simplest questions! Thank you so much.