# Align JList items (JPanels) on the left

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, alignment, jlist

I`m having problems figuring out how to align my JPanels in my JList to the left side.

I´m using a custom ListCellRenderer, so the JPanels render at all.

```
public class FileTab extends JPanel implements ListCellRenderer<FileProperties> {

    public FileTab(int w, int h) {
        setSize(w, h);
    }

    private void initComponents(FileProperties prop, boolean selected) {
        removeAll();
        JCheckBox checkBoxSelection = new JCheckBox();
        checkBoxSelection.setBounds(10, 10, 10, 10);
        add(checkBoxSelection);

        checkBoxSelection.setSelected(selected);

        System.out.println("Draw: " + prop.getFileName());
        JLabel labelFileName = new JLabel(prop.getFileName());
        labelFileName.setBounds(5, 70, getWidth() - 85, 20);
        labelFileName.setFont(new Font("Consolas", Font.ITALIC, 20));
        add(labelFileName);
    }

    @Override
    public Component getListCellRendererComponent(JList<? extends FileProperties> list, FileProperties prop, int index,
        boolean isSelected,
        boolean cellHasFocus) {
        initComponents(prop, isSelected);

        return this;
    }
}
```

And thats how I create the List:

```
JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane();
scroll.setBounds(5, 5, getWidth() - 10, getHeight() - 110);
list = new DefaultListModel<>();
fileList = new JList<>(list);
fileList.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.MULTIPLE_INTERVAL_SELECTION);
fileList.setCellRenderer(new FileTab(getWidth() - 30, 30));
scroll.setViewportView(fileList);
add(scroll);
```

This results in this, where the JPanels are aligned in the center rather than on the left side.

[image: Jpanels centered in JList]

And the updating of the list:

```
list.clear();
for (FileProperties props : files) {
    list.addElement(props);
}
fileList.setCellRenderer(new FileTab(getWidth() - 30, 30));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default a JPanel use a `FlowLayout` which by default is `center aligned`. Change the JPanel to use a `FlowLayout` that is `right aligned`:

```
JPanel panel = new JPanel( new FlowLayout(...) ); // Read FlowLayout API for proper parameter
```

Comment: I guess you mean left aligned.

Comment: Yes, sometimes the fingers don't type what the mind is thinking :)

Answer (score 1):

Your FileTab has no LayoutManager assigned (default is FlowLayout). So the two components you add (Checkbox and Label) are centered by default.

Maybe this helps: [JList text alignment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9250470/jlist-text-alignment)