# Making Strings have equal lenght

Tags: java

I want to add some texts in a JList and align it but it doesn't work . It doesnt align properly . Let's say i have two strings : `String a = "Apple juice is good"; String b = "Fun";` After using my code the string b is still shorter

```
while(isOk){
    String string = String.format("%-100s",text);

    // here i am adding the strings to a JList
    menuModel.add(menuList.getModel().getSize(), string + "L"); 
}
```

Comment: [JList text alignment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9250470/jlist-text-alignment) might help you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use a monospaced font for the rendering of the text:

```
list.setFont( new Font("monospaced", Font.PLAIN, 12) );
```